# Select the greatest number below a given number using LINQ to Objects?

Tags: .net, linq, collections

I have a simple collection of numbers:

```
Dim listNumbers As List(Of Byte) = New List(Of Byte)({1, 2, 3, 4, 5})
```

Using LINQ how can I select the greatest number of this list that is lower than a given number?

For example, if given number = 3, the greatest number is 2!

Comment: Distinct/GroupBy, Sort & Skip. :)

Comment: @bzlm: Please tell me that is a joke. That is `O(n log n)` when `O(n)` is trivially possible (and best possible).

Comment: @Jason But if I told you it was a joke, then the joke would be ruined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's VB.NET:

```
Dim listNumbers As List(Of Byte) = New List(Of Byte)({1, 2, 3, 4, 5})
Dim max As Integer = listNumbers.Where(Function(n As Integer) n < 3).Max()
Console.WriteLine(max)
```

Effectively what we are doing is finding a list of candidates (those numbers that are less than three) and then taking the maximum of the candidates.

If you need C#:

```
var listNumbers = new List<byte> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int max = listNumbers.Where(n => n < 3).Max();
Console.WriteLine(max);
```